# android:chat like list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I am building the chat app. I want to implement the list view in chat screen, some what like the [WhatsApp](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.whatsapp&hl=en) application but only text in each chat row.Can please tell me how implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this...good chatting example using list view
http://www.ece.ncsu.edu/wireless/MadeInWALAN/AndroidTutorial/index.html
then you can modify ur UI.